# Restore corrupt mongo db from WiredTiger files

Tags: database, mongodb, restore, wiredtiger

So here is my scenario:

- Today my server was restarted by our hoster (acpi shutdown).
- My mongo database is a simple docker container (mongo:3.2.18)
- Because of an unknown reason the container wasn't restarted on reboot (`restart: always` was set in docker-compose).
- I started it and noticed the volume mapping were gone.
- I restored them to the old paths, restarted the mongo container and it started without errors.
- I connected to the database and it was completely empty.

---

```
> show dbs
local  0.000GB
> use wekan
switched to db wekan
> show collections
> db.users.find();
>
```

Also I already tried `db.repairDatabase();`, no effect.

Now my `_data` directory contains a lot of *.wt files and more. ([File list](https://gist.github.com/CodeBrauer/043166b74a16cfd0b2f766584bcb3675))

I found `collection-0-2713973085537274806.wt` which has a file size about 390MiB.

This could be the data I need to restore, assuming its size.

**Any way of restoring this data?**

I already tried my luck using `wt salvage` according to [this article](http://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2016/02/10/recovering-a-wiredtiger-collection-from-a-corrupt-mongodb-installation/), but I can't get it running - still trying.

*I know backups,backups,backups! Sadly this database wasn't backuped.*

[Related GitHub issue](https://github.com/wekan/wekan-mongodb/issues/8), contains details to software.

---

**Update:**

I was able to create a .dump file with the `WiredTiger Data Engine` tool. However I can't get it imported into a mongoDB.

Comment: This question is answered on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55117229/restoring-mongodb-using-only-wt-files

Answer (score 2):

Try running a repair on the mongo db container. It should repair your database and the data should be completely restored.

Start mongo container in bash mode.

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run mongo bash

or

docker run -it mongo bash
```

Once you are inside the docker container, run mongo db repair.

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair
```

The DB should repaired successfully and all your data should be restored.

Comment: As already stated `Also I already tried db.repairDatabase();, no effect.`