# Restoring MongoDB using only .wt files

Tags: mongodb

My PC crashed. Can I use the .wt files to get my data back?

.wt files from the old MongoDB

[image]

Comment: Does simply starting mongodb not work?

Comment: No it doesn't work.

Comment: MongoDB will start with an exception. Print the exception here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can restore your `.wt` WiredTiger files downloaded from your Atlas Backup (which unzips or untar as a restore folder) to your local MongoDB.

First, make a backup of your `/data/db path`. Call it `/data_20200407/db`. Second, copy paste all the `.wt` files from your Atlas Backup restore folder into your local `/data/db path`. Restart your Ubuntu or MongoDB server. Start your Mongo shell and you should have those restored files there.

Comment: You can run mongo with a different data folder using: 
docker run -p 27017:27017 -v /atlas_restore:/data/db mongo

Comment: Doesn't work. 1) I placed all my .wt files inside the C://data/db folder, 2) ran mongod --dbpath "C:\data\db", 3) Restarted the local MongoDB Server service. Then when I open the MongoDBCompassm Client, and connect to the local MongoDB instance, there are no DB or collection from the old Database (.wt files). Can anybody help ?

Comment: * 1) I placed all my .wt files inside the C:\data\db folder

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Mongodb 5. The mongodb service will not start after the .wb files are copied

Comment: If you just copy collection.*.wt and index.*.wt files MongoDb starts but the database is not present in the explorer. In the first case the error in logs is: WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":0,"message":"[1675695400:856711][3124:140734619330384], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: int __cdecl __wt_block_read_off(), 302: WiredTiger.wt: potential hardware corruption, read checksum error for X block at offset Y

Answer (score 1):

I restored my db with some BSON files and then I repaired it so it can sync up my db and get my most recent files. I used Robo3T  to repair my DB and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Keep your wt files at location `C:\data\db` also check permissions

Go to bin folder of `mongodb` and hit following command

> mongod --dbpath "C:\data\db"

Go to same bin folder and hit mongo command there

I suggest to use `noSQLBooster` to view db and collections.
make sure you have `C:\Programfiles\mongodb\server\4.4\bin\` path set in `Environment variables`